# vs code - custom jsx intelisense with es6

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, intellisense, jsx

I have a mini internal library and want to create intellisense for users who will be using JSX.

basically, I want the user to start writing and have the available properties he needs to add in autocomplete.

type script have interfaces and models that allow it to display intellisense.
i'm looking for the same (even if i need to put some effort into that)

I'm using es6 & latest vs code.

the code is not really specifically related (can be any react code) but is here in case someone will give me direction / modification.

code sample:

```
class Button extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.onClickFunction(this.props.IncrementValue);
  }
    render(){
    return (
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.IncrementValue}</button>
    )
  }
}
const Result = (props) => {
    return (
    <div>{props.counter}</div>
  );
};
class App extends React.Component{
    state = {counter: 0};

  incrementCounter = (IncrementValue) => {
    this.setState((prevState)=>({
        counter: prevState.counter + IncrementValue
    }));
  };

    render(){
    return(
        <div>
          <Button IncrementValue={1} onClickFunction={this.incrementCounter} />
        <Button IncrementValue={5} onClickFunction={this.incrementCounter} />
          <Button IncrementValue={10} onClickFunction={this.incrementCounter} />
          <Button IncrementValue={100} onClickFunction={this.incrementCounter} />
        <Result counter={this.state.counter} />
        </div>
    )
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, mountNode);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please share the code what you have tried so far so that we can help you with resolution

Comment: Your question is not related to the code you shared. i.e., basically, I want the user to start writing and have the available properties he needs to add in autocomplete.

Comment: exactly, in typescript you have interfaces to define a structure and i just some kind of "interface" that works with es6 and jsx (i don't mind if its a vs code feature / extantion...)

Answer (score 1):

Open your VS Code [workspace settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings), and in settings.json add the following.

```
{
  "files.associations": {
    "*.js": "javascriptreact"
  },
  "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

This will enable VS Code to treat every js/jsx files under your React project with react specific configurations/ autocomplete features.
This will also enables the default code formatting on save.

Hope this helps!

Comment: hey, thanks for the effort, but i try to achieve is intellisense that know the tags that the jsx component should get (and even to add a description on the prop),
- but its good to have this in the setting anyway :)